# CGridView Sorting with relational table sorts by relaton Id parameter

Tags: yii, cgridview, yii-events

I have problem in `CGrid` while on sorting a relational data using relational model in ``  page.

### Briefly my scenario:

I have a **user** `model: Entities=> id,username`
And a **profile** `Model: Entities=> id, firstname,lastname, user_id,`etc..

I want to list `profile mode`l and `username` from `user model` in `CGrid`, so that **sorting and searching** perms well. In my case sorting  `username` is done by `user_id` not by `username`. I want to search it by `username`,so i do the following,

### My Controller Action:

```
$model = new Profile('search');
$model -> unsetAttributes();// clear any default values
if (isset($_GET['Profile']))
$model -> attributes = $_GET['Profile'];

$this -> render('MyPage', array('model' => $model ));
```

### My Model Relation:

```
public function relations() {
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name  the relations automatically generated below.

    return array(
     'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'user', 'user_id'),);
}
```

### Model Rules:

```
array( 'xxx,yyy,user_name', 'safe', 'on'=>'search' ),
```

### And model search function

```
if(!empty($this->user_id)){
$criteria->with='user'; 
$criteria->order = ::app()->request->getParam('sort');// 'username ASC'
} 

$criteria -> compare('user.username', $this->user_id, true);
```

### My

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGrid', array(
'id'=>'profile-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
 'filter'=>$model,
array('name'=>'user_id',
    'header'=>User::model()->getAttributeLabel('username'), 
    'value' =>'$data->getRelated(\'user\')->username',
    'type'=>'raw',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'text-align: center'),),
   ---------------
```

During sorting,sorting works perfectly but sorting is done on the basis of `user_id` not by `username`. Anything that i am missing to do so. Please suggest.

Reference:[Here](http://www.framework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgrid/) (I also tried as by declaring a public variable as suggesting in the link but bot workingg.)

Edit: After Issue Fixed. 
Thanks for [this](http://www.mrsoundless.com/php/yii/searching-and-sorting-a-column-from-a-related-table-in-a-cgridview/) link too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the wiki page you found is really a good start...

Here is an alternative way for doing this :

**In your Profile model :**

```
// private username attribute, will be used on search
private $_username;

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        // .....
        array('username', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        // .....
    );
}

public function getUsername()
{
    // return private attribute on search
    if ($this->scenario=='search')
        return $this->_username;

    // else return username
    if (isset($this->user_id)) && is_object($this->user))
        return $this->user->username;
}

public function setUsername($value)
{
    // set private attribute for search
    $this->_username = $value;
}

public function search()
{
    // .....
    $criteria->with = 'user'; 
    $criteria->compare('user.username', $this->username, true);
    // .....

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'attributes'=>array(
                'username'=>array('asc'=>'user.username', 'desc'=>'user.username DESC'),
                '*',
            ),
        ),
    ));
}
```

**And in your view you should simply try** :

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'profile-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        // .....
        'username',
        // .....
    ),
);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.. When i try, i get following: Error 500: <h1>CDbException</h1> <p>CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.username' in 'order clause'</p>
I think this line throws the error..
'username'=>array('asc'=>'user.username', 'desc'=>'user.username DESC'),

Comment: Make sure you set criteria `with` param : `$criteria->with = 'user';`

Comment: Yes, i did it. As you see this in my question also.

Comment: In a `if` statement like in your question ?

Comment: You got me there..! Finally fixed.